# Root Domain cannot forward to www (Heroku, Cloudns)

Tags: domain-name-system, forwarding, heroku

My website (http://www.carshare.hk) has a problem with the naked domain. 
When it is served with the root domain, the server cannot hit anything. 
But I have followed through the guides from heroku about adding domains already.

When I typed `heroku domains -a my-app`, the root domain shows it is added. 
I know that I cannot use an A record with heroku. But I am not too sure how to redirect the root to www with Cloudns.net.

Any captain here?

Comment: It's called an apex but how do you host dns for that domain?

Comment: The only way out is either to use a DNS service provider which supports 'CNAME-like functionality at the zone apex using a custom record type' (quoted from Heroku's site) or use URL forwarding as suggested by Esa below. Make sure CNAME flattening doesn't impact your other services though, such as email.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you already got this one working by using free simple redirection service from a 3rd party, since now we can get

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.example.com/
```

However, creating this kind of simple redirect could easily be handled on any server running any httpd. **Now you are relying on a 3rd party free service provider.** How can you guarantee this service:

- Will stay alive?
- Won't, under any circumstances, forward your traffic to somewhere else?
- Doesn't use this trust for any other purposes? By having an A record of your domain the service prociver can do almost anything with it: the control is not limited in HTTP traffic.

I'd suggest using any server you can manage by yourself and adding a NameVirtualHost, e.g. in Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect / http://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

I'd also suggest using generalized domain instead of your actual domain name to prevent giving away information about your configuration.

Answer (score -1):

To do this just create an **Alias**, points to www.carshare.hk and let the **host** blank.

Comment: you cannot `CNAME` at the zone level which is what an *alias* sounds like it will create

Comment: Chicks (nice alias), Andrew was asking for the problem in Cloudns.net. I answered with the procedure in Cloudns.net, not in the server. By the way, I had the same problem and I don't have anymore.